# Update a field when a button is clicked using PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, desktop-application, pyside6

I am trying to update a field (which I don't know how to make it using PySide6/Qt designer) whenever I click a button in a desktop app. The default value of `field` is set to `version 1.0`. I.E. when `upload file` button is clicked, `field` will be updated to file directory where the file was uploaded from (note that the app is cross platform: MacOS and WinOS). When `view data` is clicked, `field` will be updated to `data is in view mode`.

[image]

I have no idea what kind of PySide6 Widget that can solve this for me.

Comment: I suppose you mean a status bar. A QMainWindow already has support for it through [`statusBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#statusBar). Read the documentation to know how to change its messages or show persistent widgets/text.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to be using is QActions. A good trick is to use a QToolButton as a QPushButton and add a QAction to it, performing the code you want. For instance, some example code would be:

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction
from PySide6.QWidget import (QToolButton, 
QMainWindow,
QApplication,
QVBoxLayout, 
QStatusBar)

## Rest of your code

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.upload_action = QAction("Upload File...", self)
        self.upload_action.setStatusTip("No File Selected")
        self.upload_action.triggered.connect(self.upload_action())
        upload_btn = QToolButton(self)
        upload_btn.setDefaultAction(self.upload_action)
        self.viewdata_action = QAction("View Data", self)
        self.viewdata_action.setStatusTip("No data to view")
        self.viewdata_action.triggered.connect(self.view_data())
        viewdata_btn = QToolButton(self)
        viewdata_btn.setDefaultAction(self.viewdata_action)
        self.connect_action = QAction("Connect...", self)
        self.connect_action.setStatusTip("Connect...")
        self.connect_action.triggered.connect(self.connect())
        connect_btn = QToolButton(self)
        connect_btn.setDefaultAction(self.connect_action)
        layout.addWidget(upload_btn)
        layout.addWidget(viewdata_btn)
        layout.addWidget(connect_btn)
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar(self))
    def upload_action(self):
        file_loc = ""
        ## Your upload code here
        self.viewdata_action.setStatusTip(file_loc)
    def viewdata_action(self):
        self.viewdata_action.setStatusTip("Data is in view mode")
        ## Your view data code here
    def connect(self):
        ## Your connect code here

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Hope this helps you achieve what you're aiming for. Essentially, you create an action, add it to the button and the action has a method for changing the status bar. And since you create the actions as class attributes, they can be accessed from the methods allowing you to dynamically update the status bar text for each. The text shows up only when you hover over the button, so if you want to statically display the text and that gets updated, then you'll need to use a QLabel bound to the bottom of the window with a fixed height. You can style it to resemble a status bar in code, but that'll allow the text you want to display to persist. In this case, like with the actions, you set the QLabel as a class attribute so you can update it from methods outside the scope of the constructor.